# How to check whether a marker already exists or not in Google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have latitude and longitude of a place. I want to check whether such a marker is already present or not. How can I do it?

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long);
//before setting marker i want to check here
marker.setPosition(myLatLng);
marker.setVisible(true);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you keep an array of markers you've added to the map? If so, just compare the locations of the new marker with the old ones to find out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whenever you add a marker to the map (it's also best to add the markers to an markers array at this point), add the lat and lng to a separate lookup array.

```
var lookup = [];
lookup.push([lat, lng]);
marker.setPosition(myLatLng);
```

Then when you want to check to see if a marker is present at a particular location, loop through the lookup array:

```
var search = [51.5945434570313, -0.10856299847364426];

function isLocationFree(search) {
  for (var i = 0, l = lookup.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (lookup[i][0] === search[0] && lookup[i][1] === search[1]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

isLocationFree(search);
```

Comment: I have done some changes to your code and it is working fine.Used same logic

Comment: much appreciated +1 its very useful for me too:)

Comment: Where in the question does it mention a large set of markers?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
// mkList = [mark1, mark2, ...], existing marker container

var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long);

// check if this position has already had a marker
for(var x = 0; x < mkList.length; x++) {
    if ( mkList[x].getPosition().equals( myLatLng ) ) {
        console.log('already exist');
        return;
    }
}

var newMarker = new GoogleMap Marker - by myLatLng;
mkList.push(newMarker);
```

- Google map `LatLng` object has a method `equals()` to tell if a `LatLng` is equals to the other one
- Google map `Marker` object has a method `getPosition()` which returns a `LatLng` object
- user `marker.getPosition().equals( myLatLng )` to tell is their position are the same

Link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

Answer (score 0):

Just use the js .includes function to simplify the answers already given.

```
let markerPositions = [];
```

Then before you add a new marker just do a test:

```
if (markerPositions.includes(Lat.toString() + "," + Lng.toString()))  {
    continue;
}

//logic here to create the actual google.Maps.Marker, add it to the map, etc.

markerPositions.push(Lat.toString() + "," + Lng.toString())
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try using [getVisible()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Marker) method

```
var isVisible = marker.getVisible(); 
if ( isVisible && marker.getPosition() != myLatLng ) {
    marker.setPosition(myLatLng);
    marker.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: It is always returning true

Comment: `getVisible()` will just tell you if the current marker is set to be visuble. It won't do what you want.

Comment: Then.Is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: Use
marker.getPosition().equals(myLatLng) == false 
instead of 
marker.getPosition() != myLatLng